# TypeScript: An index signature parameter must be a 'string' or 'number' when trying to use string | number

Tags: typescript, interface, normalization

I'm attempting to create a function to normalize my arrays and it's expecting an output object that is structured like this:

```
{
  allIds: [1],
  byId: {
    1: {...}
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  allIds: ['1'],
  byId: {
    '1': {...}
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create an interface called `IOutput` to cater for this.

I've tried this:

```
interface IOutput {
  allIds: string[] | number[]
  byId: {
    [key: number | string]: any
  }
}
```

But it gives me the following error

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'. ts(1023)

It seems to work when I do this:

```
interface IOutput {
  allIds: string[] | number[]
  byId: {
    [key: number]: any
  }
}
```

OR

```
interface IOutput {
  allIds: string[] | number[]
  byId: {
    [key: string]: any
  }
}
```

But that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I've also tried this and it gives me the same error:

```
type StringOrNumber = string | number

interface IOutput {
  allIds: string[] | number[]
  byId: {
    [key: StringOrNumber ]: any
  }
}
```

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now the limitation to write indexes has been removed. An index signature parameter can be union of `number` and `string`.

```
type StringMap = { [key: string | number]: unknown };

function createStringPair(property: keyof StringMap, value: number): StringMap {
  return { [property]: value };
}
console.log(createStringPair(5, 10));
console.log(createStringPair("sum", 10));


[LOG]: {
  "5": 10
} 
[LOG]: {
  "sum": 10
}
```

Cheers, hope it helps.

Comment: in my case I had your same bug. I changed the key interface and the bug gone, like this `[key: symbol]` without need to that function . Is it the right approach to do with typescript? I am begginer. can you guide me if I am mistake something. thanks

Answer (score 21):

This is a limitation of the current way we can write indexes (this will change [soon enough](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797)). An index signature parameter can only be `number` or `string` (exactly those types, not a union of them, not literal types). You can however have two index signatures, one for `number` and one for `string`.

There is another small quick, if you have a `string` signature, you can actually index by `number` as well. So this means that if the `string` index and the `number` index have the same return type you just need the string index

```
interface IOutput {
    allIds: string[] | number[]
    byId: {
        [key: string]: any
        // [key: number]: any // Valid but not necessary
    }
}

let o: IOutput = {
    allIds: [1],
    byId: {
        1: {}
    }
}
let o2: IOutput = {
    allIds: ['1'],
    byId: {
        '1': {}
    }
}
```