# Using symbol as object-key type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, symbols

I'm trying to define an object with a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as key-type since MDN says:

> A symbol value may be used as an identifier for object properties [...]

But using it as type for the key-property:

```js
type obj = {
    [key: symbol | string]: string
}
```

results in the following error:

> TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

even it **can** be used as index-type.
I'm using the latest typescript version (`v3.7.2`), related questions I've found:

- [Typescript: destructuring an object with symbols as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004512/typescript-destructuring-an-object-with-symbols-as-keys) (He's using an actual instance of a Symbol, I want the *type* `symbol`)
- [TypeScript: An index signature parameter must be a 'string' or 'number' when trying to use string | number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831886/typescript-an-index-signature-parameter-must-be-a-string-or-number-when-try)
- [ES6: destructuring an object with symbols as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004346/es6-destructuring-an-object-with-symbols-as-keys/54004391#54004391) (That can't be a solution - it seems kinda wrong to use an actual instance as type since every Symbol instance is unique...)

I've also took a look at the [typescript symbol docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html#introduction) but they only show how it's used as value, not as type.

Example:

```js
const obj = {} as {
    [key: number | symbol]: string // Won't work
};

const sym = Symbol('My symbol');
obj[sym] = 'Hi';
```

[Issue on Microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24587)

[Open feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863)

Comment: I think TypeScript only supports specific symbols in its object type declarations. Do you really want *any* `symbol`? Maybe show an example of how you want to use your `type obj` - I doubt that all symbol-keyed properties will be `string`s.

Comment: @Bergi I've added an example, maybe I've overseen something but I can't find a way to bring ts to accept a symbol (without using `any` which is bad practice).

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24587

Comment: am not sure if am right but did you try using `Map<Symbol,String>` as we have Map , if that would serve the purpose of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Same issue for me, I guess the annoying part is the false advertising of how "TS is a superset of JS" - well, not exactly. this is a perfect example of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[TypeScript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures) allows [symbols](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html) in [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

```
type SymbolIndex = {
    [key: symbol | string]: string // works
}

const sym = Symbol("descr");
const t1: SymbolIndex = {
    "foo": "bar",
    [Symbol.iterator]: "qux",
    sym: "sym"
};

// all result in string
t1.foo 
t1.sym 
t1[Symbol.iterator]
t1["oh"]
```

[Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAyiC2AjA9gGwJIDsAmEAeUAvFAN4BQUlUA2gNYQgBcUAzgiqlAD6vABOAS0wBzALrMW-IcKgB6WVADuyPrRZkAvmTIBjZJkmsERWOzQAKAES4WOvpYCUAbl37DwAIzM4SNFlwExORUUJYAZsjIlsyWiACG9gA0FFTUPhwAdALAEHxxwCrioQCOAK54lskhbPAxNZaaLmTyUHGonHwQLKWowFBCvIIiZJ4ZEchQIx4ZNZOeaWaoWTl5BXyiU9SWyAAWlqJAA)

With older versions, `SymbolIndex` will trigger an [error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAyiC2AjA9gGwJIDsAmEAeUAvFAN4BQUlUA2gNYQgBcUAzgiqlAD6vABOAS0wBzALrMW-IcLIBfIA):

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.(1023)

#### Alternative

If you just want an object type with symbols and no index signature, you can already do that today:

```
const sym = Symbol() // note const (no let) 
type O = {
    foo: string
    [Symbol.iterator]: string
    [sym]: number
}

let o: O = { [sym] : 3, [Symbol.iterator]: "bar", foo: "qux"}

let { [sym]: symVal } = o
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbGBeGBlJAjEAbAFAJQwD0JMYIUApjKJLPpTLtVMQFBTwAOtA8qhgBvDjHEwAZiBAAuOFABOASzABzMRIDamRDlwA6ZTUUBDKCEUBdedBXrN4rQkQ2KAVz3VFHAL4cOVlg5GEE0YRhnJCsYeQBmABpI3X0jE3NLNwAiLFNFLKTpEKyAR3cADyz-QLYRSJc3FwA1U1wYXyEQIA)

Comment: If we have two `Symbol()` then how can we use `[Symbol.iterator]` for two different Symbol

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik I honestly don't understand your question. `Symbol.iterator` is a well-known symbol and can be added once per object as property key to provide [a default iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), usable with `for...of`. It is also not clear, if you mean type or value space.

Comment: I can see the code in the playground and it runs without any problem. However, after I copied them to my vscode with TypeScript 4.3, it still tells me `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)`

Comment: @Huan that feature has been delayed to upcoming TS 4.4, updated answer

Comment: Thanks, @ford04! I have updated to TypeScript 4.4-dev and everything works now.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment in TypeScript. If you have to interoperate with some APIs that expect this or *really* want to use symbols as keys, you can do this awkward version:

```js
// Ensure we can not pass regular map to our custom functions
type SymbolMapTag = { readonly symbol: unique symbol }

type SymbolMap = SymbolMapTag & {
    [Key in string | number | symbol]: string;
}

function set_symbol<T extends SymbolMap, TSym extends symbol>
(target: T, sym: TSym, value: T[TSym]) {
    target[sym] = value;
}

function get_symbol<T extends SymbolMap, TSym extends symbol>
(target: T, sym: TSym): T[TSym] {
    return target[sym];
}

const symbol_map = {} as SymbolMap;

const sym = Symbol('My symbol');
set_symbol(symbol_map, sym, "hi");
get_symbol(symbol_map, sym); // string


type NonSymbolMap = {
    [Key in string | number]: string;
}

const non_symbol_map = {} as NonSymbolMap;
set_symbol(non_symbol_map, sym, "hi"); // error
get_symbol(non_symbol_map, sym); // error
```