# why 'let' declaration symbol will convert to string index signature in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

when using `let s = Symbol()` to declare the symbol as key of an object, such as:

```
let a = { [s]:1 }
```

the type of `a` will automatically become `{[x:string]:number}` whereas it will get error when try to index like `a[s]`:

> Type 'symbol' cannot be used as an index type (2538)

while use `const s = Symbol()` declaration is work as become to `{[s]:number}`.

Comment: Probably [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24587).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118271/using-symbol-as-object-key-type-in-typescript

Comment: Do you want `a` to have *all* symbols as its keys, or just the one specified by `s`?  If the former, I don't think that's possible.  If the latter, then `const` works because the compiler knows its value won't change so it is inferred more narrowly, whereas `let` allows it to change so it is inferred as just `symbol`, which leads to the problem.

Comment: @jcalz it's latter, thanks. and just curious about the `symbol->key:string` transform behavior

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old problem. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24587.

A curious comment in the latter is

> [we forbid symbols as indexers because we have no symbol index signatures (this was a hole we patched in 2.9 - previously it would assume the string indexer type, which was very incorrect), however unique symbols - a type associated with exactly one symbol are fine, since they refer to exactly one property.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24587#issuecomment-394014604)

It seems to me like you found a case they didn't fix in 2.9 or reverted since then...